# Seek video position width video from another domain

Tags: javascript, flash, video, jwplayer, seek

http://www.67games.com/video.html

You will notice after the video starts that if you try to jump to another position in the video it will reset and start over. So that is the problem.

As you can see the source is external. This uses JW PLayer, but I have tried with other players to.

I have tried with other hosts and video formats and its the same issue. 
Can somebody help me with this cause I'm stuck?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the source media file being on another server/domain has anything to do with your problem.

You have a progressive download video here, and seeks just fine to the point of download.  Yes, it does restart from the beginning if you try and seek past the last downloaded mark, but that is to be expected.  (How could a client seek into data it doesn't even have yet?)

You have two choices:

- Tweak the player so that it **never attempts to seek beyond the last downloaded point**.  If you are only going to have clips this small that this solution seems fine.
- **Put the clip behind a streaming or psedu streaming server**.  (More appropriate for longer clips.)

  - *Streaming*: red5, Wowza, FMS, etc
  - *Pseudo streaming*: apache/lighttpd/etc with [mod_h264_streaming](http://h264.code-shop.com/trac) + some client side logic denote the position to stream to